# previous key frame color still show to all frames that make dificult to fill color in current key frame

Tags: color

[image: cute infant boy]

I used color fill to current keyframe but in previous fill color of girl which is pink color still showing to next key frame. onion skin is disabled and this fill color is showing till the end of all frame. i cant fill blue color on current key frame due to previous pink color is showing please help ?